# Hive throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when select count(1) on ORC table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a simple table with 9 fields, using ORCFile format (I followed the steps mentioned [here](http://hortonworks.com/blog/orcfile-in-hdp-2-better-compression-better-performance/)). When I try to count the number of rows in that table (350 million rows, btw) by submitting:

```
select count(1) from my_orc_table;
```

I get an '**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**'. Let me copy the stack, just in case it provides more information:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.doNextWithExceptionHandler(HadoopShimsSecure.java:304)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.next(HadoopShimsSecure.java:220)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:197)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:429)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: That's not the relevant stack. Copy everything, including all `Caused by:`

Comment: Just discovered that there's a field in the table that, if removed, everything works fine. Unable to find what values are corrupted, nor how to check field integrity...

Any ideas?